# asp.net editing the "connectionstrings.config " problem

Tags: asp.net, connection-string

Thanks in advance.

I am attempting to edit the connectionstrings.config to connect to my sql server (locally) but it does not success.

The error message shown when i test in visual studio is:
Login failed for user 'TAT-PC\TAT'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection

The content now in connectionstrings.config is:

```
  <add name="NopSqlConnection" connectionString="Data Source=TAT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=hand;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=TAT-PC\TAT;Password=;Connect Timeout=30"/>
```

The server is build by sql server 2005. And when i use the management tool to access 
the config are:

- Server type:Database Engine Server
- Name:TAT-PC\SQLEXPRESS
- Authentic:  Windows Authentic
- User Name:TAT-PC\TAT    <===Which is Not editable
- Password:  <==no  password

So, my question is how to edit the connectionstrings.config in order to connect to the server??(I have already create the schema "hand")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you assigned permission to your local user to sepcific database on sql server ? No need to mention any username or password. Just use trusted connection string.

Comment: <add name="NopSqlConnection" connectionString="Data Source=TAT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=hand;Integrated Security=true;Connect Timeout=30"/>


i have try to use this to replace the old one. Is this one correct??